# Rails 3 change default english numbers to arabic numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, numbers, arabic

I want to change the default numbers from english to arabic when the user switches to the arabic interface.

13 => ١٣

89 => ٨٩

What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this quick solution. I added the following function in the ApplicationHelper

```
def tn(num)
  num.to_s.split(//).map{|r|t("n"+r)}.join
end
```

Then added translations for each number from 0 to 9 in the `config/locals/ar.yml` with the format below:

```
n1: "١"
n2: "٢"
n3: "٣"
.
.
.
```

Now we can call the new numeric translation function by `tn(13)` which will output `١٣` in arabic localization

Answer (score 1):

I add in helper module

```
ARABIC_NUMBERS = %w(٠ ١ ٢ ٣ ٤ ٥ ٦ ٧ ٨ ٩)
def ta numbers
  numbers = numbers.to_s if numbers.is_a? Integer
  results = numbers.chars.map { |char| ARABIC_NUMBERS[char.to_i] }.join
end
```

Comment: if you want this solution to sovle negative number you must check if char == '-' else do what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code : https://github.com/gdotdesign/rails-arabic-convert/blob/master/app/helpers/convert_helper.rb.

It's a helper to convert a english number to an arabic number.

Comment: could change the words in numbers in this script?