# Best way to handle foreign number in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, number-formatting, rails-i18n

I wonder something. We have an rails app that had been translated in 30/40 languages including exotic languages. We wonder what's the best way to handle numbers and number translation.

For example, we have in english, a string `3 items`, but in persian or arabic, it will become something like `٣ سلع`‎. Unfortunately, I am getting `3 سلع` using `I18n` gem.

I am using this file as locale:

https://raw.github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/master/rails/locale/ar.yml

The locale is correclty set to `ar` it just output 3 in place of ٣ (the arabic/persian character)

Any ideas?

Comment: I actually don't see digits defined in your file...am I missing something?

Comment: Someone else had the exact same problem and found a solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800798/rails-3-change-default-english-numbers-to-arabic-numbers

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't seems really elegant though as you have to build helpers for each languages, nobody have done a gem to handle that? Sounds like a pretty common issue.

Comment: I've answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124562/localization-of-numeric-number-in-rails/18182725#18182725