# Localization of numeric number in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, internationalization, numbers

[Sorry for the new post, but my first one was focusing to arabic/persian numbers but it seems the issue is larger.]

I wonder if someone had done a gem to handle the localization of numeric number in ruby/rails. I18n official locales (https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale) seems not to take care of that.

It's kind of complex to do by helpers.

Arabic is simple:

`٠  ١   ٢   ٣   ٤   ٥   ٦   ٧   ٨   ٩`

Persian too:

```
۰   ١   ۲   ۳   ۴   ۵   ۶   ۷   ۸   ۹   ۱۰
```

But all languages don't match 1-1 conversion with english, Chinese for example:

```
0: 〇 (零) líng
1: 一 (壹) yī
2: 二 (Simplified:贰;Traditional:貳) èr
3: 三 (Simplified:叁;Traditional:叄、參) sān
4: 四 (肆) sì
5: 五 (伍) wǔ
6: 六 (Simplified:陆;Traditional:陸) liù
7: 七 (柒) qī
8: 八 (捌) bā
9: 九 (玖) jiǔ
10: 十 (拾) shí
100: 百 (佰) bǎi
1000: 千 (仟) qiān
10,000: Simplified:万;Traditional萬 wàn
100,000,000: Simplified:亿;Traditional億 yì
1,000,000,000,000: 兆 zhào
```

We have other language with similar issues. It seems weird that nobody seems to have face that before.

Do you know the best way to handle the number in all locales?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Added a explicit question, I was think it was obvious.

Comment: A question is only obvious if it **is** explicit. It may have been obvious to you, but you knew what you were asking.

Comment: Sure, I meant it already have this: `I wonder if someone had done a gem to handle the localization of numeric number in ruby/rails.` But, yeah I can see why it can be confusing so I edited.

Comment: I don't understand why I keep having closed votes after the edition though...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I've come up with that:

```
  def number to_convert, locale, text = nil,
    to_convert = to_convert.to_i.to_s
    case locale
    when 'ar'
      to_convert = to_convert.unpack('U*').map{ |e| e + 1584 }.pack('U*')
      text ? to_convert + ' ' + text : to_convert
    when 'fa'
      to_convert = to_convert.unpack('U*').map{ |e| e + 1728 }.pack('U*')
      text ? to_convert + ' ' + text : to_convert
    when 'hi'
      to_convert = to_convert.unpack('U*').map{ |e| e + 2358 }.pack('U*')
      text ? to_convert + ' ' + text : to_convert
    else
      text ? to_convert + ' ' + text : to_convert
    end
  end
```

Other language don't need custom localization. Ie. Chineese/Japanese people understand our number and it will be weird to support their local number as local people are using our number on the web.

Comment: cool - are yo planning to contribute this to rails? would be useful to have support for all languages built in.